# Is there a way to make DateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime work on a machine with GMT/UTC time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to know if there is a way to make a `DateTime` object get all the right properties on a OS that is set to GMT time. Not just changing time.

Right now what im doing is:

```
DateTime f = new DateTime(2012, 8, 1); //A date on summer

DateTime f2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(f, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Central Europe Standard Time");

var isSummer = f2.IsDaylightSavingTime(); //It always returns false if the OS is on GMT
```

And it changes the hour & date to make the GMT become Central Europe Standard Time just fine, but the `IsDaylightSavingTime` function wont work. It always returns false because I'm using GMT on the system, but i think it shouldn't because I created a `DateTime` for central Europe.

Is there a way to make the `DateTime` object `f2` really local and make it understand that if its August and is European Central it should return true instead of false?

I know if I use local time on the machine it would work OK, but I cant change the GMT time on the server. I would love to, but I cant. :-)

Comment: Of course, i want to clarify im not worried about August, what i dont want to make is my own function to know if is the exact day the hour changes. And even then, it depends on the location since the data im using is of flights on different time zones.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/1583

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DateTime.IsDayLightSavingTime returns true if Kind is Local or Unspecified, and the value of this instance of DateTime is within the Daylight Saving Time range for the current time zone

I.e. DateTime object checks with system time zone, since UTC does not support daylight saving, it returns true.

If you want to verify, if the time specified fall in daylight saving for a time zone, then use IsDayLightSavingTime method in TimeZoneInfo

```
DateTime f = new DateTime(2012, 8, 1); //A date on summer 
TimeZoneInfo tzf2=TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
DateTime f2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(f, tzf2);
var isSummer = tzf2.IsDaylightSavingTime(f2);
```

Comment: Sorry, we need to use tzf2.IsDaylightSavingTime(f2) to validate If it is DLSTime.